# Calculating the surface area of a curve

Tags: calculus

$$y=\frac{x^2}{32}$$ rotated about the y-axis, from $x \in [0,8]$

I'm using the following approach, but I keep getting the answer wrong.

$$A= \int_{0}^2 2 \pi x \sqrt{1+\frac{x^2}{16^2}}\,d x$$

When I integrate this, I get:

$$\frac{512}{3} \pi (\frac{x^2}{256}+1)^\frac{3}{2}|_0^8=\frac{128}{3} \pi$$

However, this is wrong.  I'm positive that it should be right. Am I wrong, or is the answer the book gives wrong?

Comment: What was the book's answer?

Comment: It should be $dy$ not $dx$. So express the $2\pi x\sqrt{}$ in terms of $y$.

Answer (score 0):

Indefinite integral

$ \frac  {1}{24} \pi ( 256 + x^2)^{3/2}$

Evaluated in the interval $(x,0,8)$

$ \frac {216}{3} \pi= 72 \pi $